# Python Cmd Module Multi-line input

Tags: python, cmd

why the python `Cmd` module command prompt not using multi-line? it's over writing the same line

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INZpp.png)

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sorry I don't know, hw to answer ques in stackoverflow, but I found it finally

use `self.use_rawinput = False` this will fix the problem (If you want a given stdin to be used, make sure to set the instance’s use_rawinput attribute to False, otherwise stdin will be ignored.)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html